How do you update/change the schema of old database tables?
How can you easily modify the old tables using raw SQL?
Well, until now I worked with django, and when I had to make a change on a table (add a new column, delete a column, modify a column, add a constraint, index, etc.) everything was easy because I made the changes in the class/model that represented the table and then run the two specific django commands (makemigrations and migrate), and the magic happened.
Now, I only use raw SQL code (no django or any other ORM). Just Python and SQL code.
Let me describe a little what happens in my little project, in a simpler way:
When I press a button, x tables are created for an instance that are populated with information about that instance.
A command to create a table is
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1_instace1(

id varchar(30) primary key,

name varchar(50) not null,

date timestamp with time zone default now()

)

The problem is the following:
At some point, I will have to modify these tables. To add a column, to add an index or many others. For future instances, the tables will have these changes, but for old instances, how do I do this? How do I make all the old tables have the changes made and applied?
I know that I have to run ALTER TABLE commands, but if I have 1 million instances and 1000 tables for each instance, I could not write so many commands.
The ideal would be to somehow detect these changes and apply them automatically, or generate these ALTER TABLE commands for me automatically and then write a script to apply them.
I have NO idea how to do this.
Could you please help me?

I think this is probably too broad and/or opinionated to answer here. FWIW, I define all of my tables in my most recent project using SQLAlchemy and then use none of the ORM features other than the engine it provides. This means that I can use Alembic for auto-generated migrations but just write regular SQL queries

You probably want some kind of tool that has Migrations.
